# Выборка mysql по количеству тегов

Tags: mysql

Есть база news (id, name, text, date, tags). Теги идут в формате tiny text просто как строка #tag1 #tag2 #tag3 #tag4.

Есть новость 1 с тегами: #tag1 #tag2 #tag3 #tag4
Есть новость 2 с тегами: #tag1
Есть новость 3 с тегами: #tag2 #tag3 #tag4
Есть новость 4 с тегами: #tag3 #tag4

Сейчас теги получаются: `select * from news where tags like '%#".$Tag." %' order by date DESC`
Как получить к новости 1 другие новости в порядке *Новость 3 - Новость 4 - Новость 1*, то есть просто по количеству совпадений тегов именно одним запросом без изменения структуры БД?

Comment: Думаю, лучше изменить БД: вынести теги в отдельную таблицу; то есть реализовать реляционную БД. [Вот](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/relational-databases-for-dummies--net-30244), статья хорошая.

Comment: Я понимаю, что лучше, но этого сделать нет возможности!

Comment: Не умею != нет возможности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL может что либо считать, только если оно представлено отдельными строками. Поэтому очень желательно что бы данные были в [нормальной форме](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). Если переделка кода под правильную структуру БД не представляется возможной, то нам придется развернуть строку с тегами в отдельные строки в самом запросе и потом посчитать количества совпадений. Для этого нам понадобится служебная таблица с порядковыми номерами от 0 до максимально возможного количества тегов в строке:

```
create table seqnum(X int not null);
-- Первые 8 записей
insert into seqnum values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7);
-- И еще 512
insert into seqnum
select s1.x*64+s2.x*8+s3.x+8
  from seqnum s1, seqnum s2, seqnum s3;
```

Запрос для поиска всех новостей с такими же тегами, как в новости с ID=1, с сортировкой по совпадениям выглядит так:

```
select N.*,count(1) cnt
  from news N,
       (select ltrim(substr(tags,length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,' ',s.x))+1,
               length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,' ',s.x+1))-
               length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,' ',s.x)))) tag
          from news n, seqnum s
         where n.id=1
           and length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,' ',s.x))<length(tags)
       ) T
 where concat(N.tags,' ') like concat('%',T.tag,' %')
   and N.id!=1
group by N.id
order by cnt desc
```

Подзапрос `T` вытаскивает все теги новости ID=1 отдельными строками, внешний запрос ищет совпадения и считает их количества. Вырезка тегов из строки основана на предположении, что теги строго разделены одним пробелом.