# mysql , какой функцией можно получить из одной строки неопределённое заранее количество подстрок, разделённых по шаблону?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

К примеру есть таблица с полем `BLOB`, в поле значение формата с содержимым ниже 
`POLYGON ((47.75458 8.19211,47.7598 8.19413,47.76013 8.19398,47.75458 8.19211))`

Полигон может быть из нескольких тысяч точек. 
содержимое поля можем получить как `` AsText(`GeoShape`) ``

Как запросом SQL получить несколько тысяч строк из одной такой строки, причём каждая новая строка чтобы в себе содержала информацию только об одной точке, к примеру:

```
47.75458 8.19211
47.75980 8.19413
47.76013 8.19398
47.75458 8.19211
```

Comment: Таких функций в MySQL нет. можно только примерно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536999/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-mysql-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2/537044#537044