# Нормализовать БД mySQL товаров с категориями - перенести категории в отдельную таблицу

Tags: mysql, нормализация-данных

Изначально имеется одна таблица с товарами:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    ...
    categories TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

В поле categories для каждой записи через запятую+пробел перечисляются категории товара в текстовом виде, например:

```
'Телевизоры, Электротехника'
'Косметика, Распродажа, Подарочные наборы'
```

и т.д.

Таким образом одному товару соответствует одна или несколько категорий.

Создал две пустые таблицы, которые нужно заполнить:

1) таблица категорий (считаем, что категории одного уровня, без вложенности)

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

2) таблица для связи двух предыдущих таблиц (многие ко многим)

```
CREATE TABLE prodsCats (
    productID INT(11) NOT NULL,
    categoryID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (productID,`categoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Я вижу структуру БД после нормализации в следующем виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне заполнить таблицы categories и prodsCats с помощью SQL?

Comment: Думаю вам надо для себя разделить вопрос на части и выяснять как сделать каждый из пунктов по отдельности. Например разворачивание списка через разделитель из поля в нормальную форму это явно отдельная задача и не самая простая, решаемая как то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536999/194569

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал так:

1. В таблице "prodsCats" - добавил бы 1 столбец с "AUTOINCREMENT" название ID //номер записи.
2. a.Если на чистом SQL - тогда в ручную заполнить таблицу Categories и prodsCats

   b.Если через PHP - тогда делаем PHP+SQL

   I. Вытаскиваем все товары с категориями

   II. Выясняем к-во категории по к-ву подстрок ", " в строке котегории + 2.

   III. Отбавляя по одной категории проверяем если мы её не обрабатывали ранее:

   1).ЕСЛИ категория существует тогда выясняем её ID

   2).ЕСЛИ категория встречается в первые тогда добавляем в массив для проверки, добавляем эту категорию в таблицу категорий + выясняем её ID

   3).В таблице объединения товара с категорией добавляем запись Товар(ID) - Категория(ID)

P.S. Могут быть ошибки в коде так как писал сразу сюда и без проверки...

```
 $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

 $sql = SELECT id,categories FROM products WHERE categories !='';
 $result = mysqli_query($lin,$sql);
 $cats=[];
 if($result){
    WHILE($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       if($row["categories"]!=''){

          $cat_row = $row["categories"];
          for($i=0;$i<substr_count($cat_row, ', ');$i++){

             $pos = strpos($cat_row, ', ');
             $cat = substr($cat_row, 0, $pos);
             $cat_row = substr($cat_row, $pos, strlen($cat)+2);

             if(in_array($cat,$cats)){
                $sql_cat_id = "SELECT `id` FROM `categories` WHERE `name`='{$cat}'";
                $result_cat_id = mysqli_query($link,$sql_cat_id);
                $cat_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_cat_id);
                $cat_id = $cat_id["id"];
             }else{
                $cats[]=$cat;
                $sql_cat = "INSERT INTO `categories`(`name`)VALUES('{$cat}') ";
                $result_cat = mysqli_query($link,$sql_cat);
                $cat_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);                 
             }

             $sql_prod_cat = "INSERT INTO `prodsCats`(`productId`,`categoryId`)VALUES('{$row['id']}','{$cat_id}') ";
             $result_prod_cat = mysqli_query($link,$cat_id);

          }


       } 
    }
};
```

`